# How see the data of my data base H2, why localhost:8080/h2_console not work?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, console, h2

I want to see the data in my database h2. I do not know what I'm wrong about
I have this configuration in file .properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

#spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:validate
```

when i make a request in chrome http://localhost:8080/h2_console
i get this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri May 10 00:37:28 BOT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

this my controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Friendship;
import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/user"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

   @GetMapping(path = {"/"})
public Meet getBook() {
    log.info("HELLO WORDL");
    return null;
} 
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.info("CREATE");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userServiceImpl.createUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @PostMapping("/addFriend")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestParam("owner") Long ownerId, @RequestParam("friend") Long friendId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userServiceImpl.createLinkWithFriends(ownerId, friendId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/owner/{id}/friends")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getFriendsOf(@PathVariable("id") Long ownerId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userServiceImpl.getFriendsOf(ownerId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        log.info("getUser");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userServiceImpl.getUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFriends/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(@PathVariable("id")  int id) {
        log.info("showFriends"+id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userServiceImpl.getUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

When I use this `http://localhost:8080/user/` I get this message from the controller
**Hello World!**

this is my path of my project:

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\txts\aquiesta\springTeam\traslateInClick\src\main\resources\application.properties
```

this is my repo https://github.com/hubmanS/traslateInClick

this is my dependency.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show me your entity? I think there is an incompatible data type in your entity. Maybe you first create your entity with a field string and you changed it to Integer afterwards. It only changes in your Java object and doesn't change in the database.

Comment: @ToePyaeSoneOo i edited my question. see please the error

Comment: Can you please show the path of your application properties file?

Comment: @XeshanJ i edited my question, see please

Comment: @yaha can you please share your whole spring boot console logs here.

Comment: @Abhijeet i get this mesagge 2019-05-10 17:37:32.126  WARN 7436 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/h2_console] in DispatcherServlet with name '
dispatcherServlet'
2019-05-10 17:37:33.482  WARN 7436 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name
'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: @yaha can you share whole logs? I need all the logs from start. The message will be around start of the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code below looks like your context path is also "" (blank).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/"})
public class MeetController{
...
}
```

And according to code in the controller class, the issue is with your URL mapping only. Your URL `/h2_console` is getting conflicted with `/{id}` URL of `getBook` method.

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public Meet getBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return null;
    }
```

I would suggest you add the correct context path for your application so that your application URL will not get conflicted with `h2-console` URL. The above configurations are sometimes running and failing other times. Your console will open if h2 database context URL gets registered, if it fails to get register, you will get the error page you are getting right now.

> Recommended Solution :
>
> application.properties (Commenting other h2 attributes as they are default)

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
#spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.datasource.password=
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

> MeetController:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Meet;
import com.example.demo.service.MeetServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/book"})
public class MeetController {

    @Autowired
    MeetServiceImpl bookService;

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String home(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public Meet getBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return null;
    }

    @PostMapping("/create/{name}/author/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Meet> createBook() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So your final URLs will be :

To get the book: http://localhost:8080/book/{id}/

To create a book: http://localhost:8080//create/{name}/author/{id}/

To call home: http://localhost:8080/book/

**To access h2 DB Console: http://localhost:8080/h2_console/login.jsp**

Comment: i modify this @RequestMapping({"/book"}), but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

You have a URL mapping conflict caused by one of your GET method

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
public Meet getBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return null;
}
```

`h2_console` would be mapped to `getBook` method as a string, and throws an exception as your method only accepts int. [With RESTful naming strategy in mind](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/), you should change your mapping to:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/books/{id}"})
public Meet getBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: all endpoint is mapping good, but i how to see the data of h2-bd ?